# how to get stock price of NSE market per 10 sec for web application in stock portfolio in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android project for stock portfolio and I want to get stock price of running stock market per 10 second so that I can make transaction directly through android mobile. so help me if you know anything.....

Comment: There is potentially allot to your request ... do you have an endpoint you can hit for the data (to start with)?

Answer (score 0):

many variables in your question! How fast you need to access the stock? how accurate the data need to be? how many stocks are you trying to gather data for?

But you can look at true data service. It's quite cheap and reliable.