# Get price of a stock programmaticallly

Tags: java, android, stockquotes

I am looking to fetch the price of bse and nse stocks(India) programmatically in android. I have looked at:

[how to get stock price of NSE market per 10 sec for web application in stock portfolio in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669534/how-to-get-stock-price-of-nse-market-per-10-sec-for-web-application-in-stock-por)

and a couple of other sites but the source code to do this is not available anywhere. How do I do it? (The 20 minute delay is acceptable and not an issue).

Are there any good sites that explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out service which you can access to get NSE stock prices. This [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android) will help you to access web service through android app. Just give appropriate values for `SOAP_ACTION`, `OPERATION_NAME`, `WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE` and `SOAP_ADDRESS`.
Check this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android).

Answer (score 2):

USE Yahoo.finannce service. It will come in CSV file. Each file you can read after passing Company name like:

```
BHEL.NS means BHEL Nifty:
```

If you get only nifty Sensex Live price It will generate Like:

[image]

It will be easy I had done in my app.

Comment: Doesnt .NS mean nse and not nifty

Comment: is it legal to use this in commercial android applications ?

Comment: Yahoo finance is free. its legal but approx 15 min delay